# Neural Net vs Multiple Linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, neural-networks, deep-learning

I am trying to understand what neural nets have in common with multiple linear regressions. Is is correct that every node in every layer (not counting the input layer) is just a multiple regression with the variables being the nodes in the preceding layer? I've included a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19kud.jpg) to show what I mean. How is this understanding wrong/right?

[image]